# Using sql with index in linq query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, indexing

I'm using a dbcontext linq query:

```
var list = context.MyTable.Where(x => x.IsValid).ToList();
```

The SqlProfiler shows this Sql Query:

```
SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE IsValid = 1
```

The problem is that in this table I'm using a lot of sql indexes, and by default it uses the wrong index and query is taking a very long time. I need to add the index I have in the table into the query.

In other words how to get this query from linq?

```
SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WITH(INDEX(PK_MyIndexName)) WHERE IsValid = 1
```

Comment: There is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26761827/613130) one, using interceptors

Comment: I'd rather want to find out what makes SS ignore this index and try fix that (maybe by `CREATE STATISTICS`). If you forget about adding this hint you could get into trouble if the query shape changes later.

Comment: SQL Server is probably capable of planning such a simple query. Maybe a scan really is the better choice here. sp_updatestats and retry. How many rows does the table have and how many are matched by IsValid = 1?